# A better solution for an AlertDialog with an EditText

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-edittext, ime

I would like an AlertDialog with an EditText field in it to accept input.  This in itself is pretty straight-forward.  However there are a few "obvious" features that I would like as fallout from this request.  I'll take them one-by-one.  I am looking for anyone that has a simpler solution to these things.  I am guessing the solution is, "Write your own custom dialog you lazy bum."

**`AlertDialog` with an `EditText`**

```
final EditText input = new EditText(context);
final AlertDialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).
    setTitle("Title").
    setView(input).
    setCancelable(false).
    setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which)
        {
            /* Handle ok clicked */
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).
    setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which)
        {
            /* Handle cancel clicked */
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }).create();
dlg.show();
```

Yay, works great.  It'd sure be nice if that input field got focused right away (and show the keyboard), right?

**`AlertDialog` with focused `EditText`**
The following code would be after `create()` and before `dlg.show()`

```
/** This requires API Level 8 or greater. */
dlg.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog)
    {
        input.requestFocus();
        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(input, 0);
    }
});
```

Nice job... I guess.  Now that I have this focused input it'd be nice if it respected the inputs IME option...

**`AlertDialog` with focused `EditText` with a custom IME Option**

```
input.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
input.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(final TextView v, final int actionId, final KeyEvent event)
    {
        /** Same code here that goes in the dialog.setPositiveButton OnClickListener */
        dlg.dismiss();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Now that's really not a great solution (repeated code) but it works...

Do people have a better way of solving this problem, or is it really that rare to ask a user for a small piece of information in a dialog, or am I just a winer and should go write my own dialog?

Comment: Why not just move all the repeated code into a method like `setUpImeDialog(AlertDialog dlg, EditText input) { ... }`?

Comment: @Eric Clearly you would.  Still less than ideal that you have to listen for a done (or whatever) IME event AND a click ok request.

Comment: Yes, but you can have the IME event trigger the click. Like so: `dlg.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick();`. It's still a secondary event, but it avoids repeated code. (If this is what you're looking for, I can add it as an answer.)

Comment: @Eric that certainly makes it better.  Add it as an answer to the repeated code issue.  Hopefully it helps people out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*As per comments on the OP:*

You do not have to have such repeated code in the `OnEditorActionListener`. Instead of repeating the code, you can tell the OS to click the "Ok" button when it is activated.

Something like this:

```
public boolean onEditorAction(final TextView v, final int actionId, final KeyEvent event) {
    dlg.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick(); // Click OK button
    return true;
}
```

Overall I would say you are taking the right approach ([documentation about collecting information through dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)). As I mentioned in a comment, the OS uses an `AlertDialog` w/ `EditText` for adding dictionary words (to the user dictionary), so this is an expected functionality in the OS.

Answer (score 2):

You can always switch to an `Activity` with `Theme.Dialog` theme or a `DialogFragment` which gives you a lot more freedom in tuning your widgets. `AlertDialogs` are probably better for displaying information. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually I would disagree. [The documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) shows ways to have it collecting information rather than displaying it. Also, an example baked into the OS: adding dictionary words.

Comment: @Egor I think before anyone goes and creates a new Activity, they should consider creating a Dialog with their own layout and do what they want that way.